# using include files to prevent double coding

Tags: php

My try:

1st File (connopen.php)

```
<?php
    try {
        $db = new PDO(DB_DSN, DBUSER, DB_PASSWORD);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die('Cannot connecto to database!');
    }

    try {
        $db->beginTransaction();
```

Other Files (file1.php, file2.php ...)

```
<?php
    include('connopen.php');

    ...some code using SQL(SELECT, INSERT INTO, UPDATE, DELETE ....)

    include('connclose.php');
?>
```

Last File (connclose.php)

```
<?php
        $db->commit();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $db->rollBack();
        ..some code to log errors
    }
    $db = null;
?>
```

This as is, throws an Error (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /connopen.php on line 11) because I start **try {** on connopen.php and I closed on connclose.php

If there is another way to do something like that to prevent double-triple coding... of connopen and connclose source code will appreciate. thanks

Comment: your DB close file isn't parsed yet, so you get a sytax error as you can't break up statements through multiple includes as you have.

Answer (score 1):

You have significant error in syntax because of breaking try statement.

The connection file should be just

```
  <?php
    try {
        $db = new PDO(DB_DSN, DBUSER, DB_PASSWORD);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die('Cannot connecto to database!');
    }
```

The right pattern is to create one file with application bootstraping (settings, db and external services connections, etc.) which routes the script execution to different php-scripts (file1.php, file2.php) acording the URL parsing results.

Comment: I also have try to delete the first try catch as you prefer, but the result was the same

Comment: `'connclose.php'` also has syntax errors because its try body has no beginnig. you should remove `include('connclose.php');` too.

Comment: Yes I know that! And That is the question, Another way to start TRY on connopen.php and TRY closes on the connclose.php to prevent double coding of catch for example :)

Comment: In answer update I described my vision of correct pattern to optimize the code and avoid double-coding which is implemented in lots of popular MVC-frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.
Just get rid of connclose.php, transactions and try..catches - you don't need them.
So, the code become plain and simpke

1st File (connopen.php)

```
<?php
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
);
$db = new PDO(DB_DSN, DBUSER, DB_PASSWORD, $opt);
```

Other Files (file1.php, file2.php ...)

```
<?php
    include('connopen.php');

    ...some code using SQL(SELECT, INSERT INTO, UPDATE, DELETE ....)
```

Comment: the error become of try started in connopen.php and closed in connclose.php. thanks for that improve anyway

Comment: this is not an "improvement". this is complete code you need.